# Entity Framework 4.0 POCO and Many-to-Many problem

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I have created POCO domain objects that map to the entities in the entity domain model.
Everything was working fine until now when I have to work with the many-to-many relationship.

Let's say I have three tables.
    **- Blog

    - BlogTag

    - Tag**

You can see that Blogs and Tags are many-to-many with a bridge table, BlogTag that contains a foreign key to both tables.

I also have corresponding domain models:
   **- Blogs

   - BlogsTags

   - Tags**

Now, I select a list of blogs and I'm trying to access a particular tag from a blog.

**myBlog.BlogsTags[0].Tag**

BlogTags[0].TagForeignKey is filled in, but BlogTags[0].Tag is **null** !!

I also have LazyLoading turned on.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Okay. Here's some source code.

my context class

```
public class MyContext : ObjectContext
    {
        public MyContext() : base(Utility.GetConnectionString(...), "containerName")
        {
            Blogs = CreateObjectSet<Blog>();
            BlogsTags = CreateObjectSet<BlogTag>();
            Tags = CreateObjectSet<Tags>();

            base.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        }

        public ObjectSet<Blog> Blogs { get; private set; }
        public ObjectSet<BlogTag> BlogsTags { get; private set; }
        public ObjectSet<Tags> Tags { get; private set; }
    }
```

and my poco classes just have a list of related objects with the virtual keyword.

Comment: A little more code might help diagnose the issue.  I can verify that many to many is working fine.  I have Many user entities which can have many roles and vise versa.  
I am using a repository pattern where I have a generic repository with an object context property that returns the active EF context.  Inside the constructor for the EF Context retrieval I set the Lazyloading to true:
base.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

Answer (score 2):

BlogTag shouldn't be an entity at all : it is only a relationship, it doesn't contain any actual data. If the relationship is properly modeled in your database using foreign keys, the Entity Model designer should realize that and eliminate BlogTag from the conceptual model...

---

EDIT:

I'm not sure why lazy loading doesn't work here, but you could always use `Include` to load the `Tag` explicitly :

```
var myBlog = context.Blogs.Include("BlogTags.Tag").First(b => b.Id = blogId);
var tag = myBlog.BlogsTags[0].Tag;
```

Comment: Let's say BlogTag is needed (contains a few more columns), which it does, and EF automatically figured out that it has other columns and adds that entity to the model. What doesn't make sense to me is why  the Tag property comes up as null all the time.

Comment: This won't work. That is the way I had it, but it won't work. I also realized that this is always the case when going from Many to One. That One property is always null. This sounds like a possible bug in the beta version

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the relationship properties that you are accessing in the Entity are defined as "virtual" otherwise they will not be traversed automatically.

I had the same problem...eg. of my user entity:

```
public class User : EntityBase
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; } //VIRTUAL here is KEY!
}
```

I assume your's should be:

```
 public class Blog
        {

     public string Owner { get; set; }
     public string BlogText { get; set; }
     public virtual List<BlogTag> BlogTags { get; set; }  //VIRTUAL here is KEY!

    }
```

Comment: Yes they are already virutal. It was needed for lazy loading.